# Sequential counting with preg_replace

Tags: php

I'm trying to do some seuqential counting thru a text file full of lines with preg_replace in PHP... While the code below works for me... It's counting in reverse... Anyone know how I can get the results to start from 1 instead of counting down to one???

```
$num = count($lines);
$return = preg_replace('%\$postnum%msi','post' . $num, $return);
```

It returns:

```
post10
post9
post8
post7
post6
post5
post4
post3
post2
post1
```

I want it to return this:

```
post1
post2
post3
post4
post5
post6
post7
post8
post9
post10
```

Any suggestions?? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [array_reverse()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)?

```
$return = array_reverse(preg_replace('%\$postnum%msi','post' . $num, $return));
```

Generic example using the output from the question:

http://codepad.org/VYQ9VTwM

Answer (score 0):

```
$return = array('post10',
'post9',
'post8',
'post7',
'post6',
'post5',
'post4',
'post3',
'post2',
'post1');

$result = array_reverse($return);
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/af4bd.php)

It 
could help